# JQuery apply a palette color to anything in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div contain 3 colors which is my palette and i want to change the color of button, text ,icon etc by clicking to this div

This is the html code:

```
<div class="colorPalet left">
    <div id="colorsPal">
        <div class=" left colorZone" style="background-color:#703d57;"></div>               
        <div class=" left colorZone" style="background-color:#b37ba4;"></div>
        <div class="left colorZone" style="background-color:#d9b8c4;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my palette:

[the div palette image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsc4s.png)

Comment: How are you going to select which buttons, links, icons etc... you want to change the colour of?

Comment: i will select them by there ids or class names

Comment: Use "css variables", "element.onclick" and "element.style" .

Comment: So you want to get each of the colors from the clicked` colorPalet` element and then use them to color other elements?

Comment: yes exactly @eskimo

Comment: Have a [look at this](https://jsfiddle.net/bnkvqdnL/) (click the box with the grey border)

Comment: thank you for you effort but it dosesn't work @eskimo

Comment: @dorsafdhouibi what doesn't work? the fiddle works, what doesn't it do that you need to do?

Comment: @BrettGregson  the color doesn't apply.I try it with a link but nothing change

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    function colorize(elem) {
        color = elem.style.backgroundColor;
        document.getElementById("a").style.color = color;
    }
</script>
```

Use it inside your divs:

```
<div onclick="colorize(this)"></div>
```

To make the handling more easy, use the css3 "variables". You can set them using js and you can use them inside of your css. This is still experimental.
Css:

```
body {
  --color:#fff;
}

.allcoloredelements {
  background-color:var(--color);
}
```

Add this in the above js:

```
body.style.setProperty("--color", color);
```